# Developing SFML framework

Tags: c++, sfml

I created an exemple in which i have 2 windows opened at the same time and window1 cant handle events while window2 is open. I changed the current window's color to ilustrate that its working(while window1 is open if i move the mouse, window2 gets greener and greener). But even though window1 cant handle events while window 2 is open, i cant still change window1 position. I want to be unable to do that.

```
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;

sf::Event event;

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window1(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Window1");
    sf::RenderWindow window2(sf::VideoMode(300, 300), "Window2");

    int r=0,g=0;
    while (window1.isOpen())
    {

        if(window2.isOpen()==false)
            while (window1.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window1.close();
                r=(r+1)%255;
            }
        else
        {
            while (window2.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window2.close();
                g=(g+1)%255;
            }
        }
        window1.clear(sf::Color(r,0,0));
        window1.display();


        window2.clear(sf::Color(0,g,0));
        window2.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't direct functionality in SFML for this (although I expect it's possible using platform specific code), but there are a couple of work arounds:

1. Change the window style to sf::Style::None. This is quick and easy, but has the effect of removing the title bar and window border, which you may not want.
2. Brute force the window position, either by manually setting the position each render, or checking for a position change and reversing it.